# Get single integer variable from url in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

Im new in java and android studio and i play a bit with external data, and I fail with reading json or anything.

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int a;
    Button button;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(imgButtonHandler);
    }


    View.OnClickListener imgButtonHandler = new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
           // Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PostDataActivity.class);
                 ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

            String url = "http://www.example.com/data.json";

            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
                    (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            TextView z = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                            z.setText("Response: " + response.toString());
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            TextView z = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                            z.setText("Blad");

                        }
                    });

            switch(a) {
                default:
                    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.main);
                    TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
                    t.setText("Gotowy");
                    a=1;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.poprawny);
                    TextView b = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
                    b.setText("Poprawny");
                    a=2;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.stop);
                    TextView c = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
                    c.setText("Stop");
                    a=0;
                    break;
            }
         }
    };
}
```

textView2 do not show anything exept default text.

My goal is to get one single int variable from json or php echo and print it on textView or even better have it as public variable.

I try with many examples from the OKhttp, json, generic_asynctask but im fail.

Comment: Write default: statement below case1 and case2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the request to the `RequestQueue` like following:

```
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

Otherwise it never gets run through.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Volley? If yes, you need to actually enqueue your request. Something like
`requestQueue.addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest)`

Also, the callbacks will be called on a background thread. You have to post them to the UI thread to be able to modify the view states.